# what is wrong with constraints in my UIImageView and why I cannot stretch the image on my UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, nslayoutconstraint

This is my current situation:

[image]

I have a `UIViewController` with `UIImageView` on it.

The latter has the following constraints: `trailing to superview`, `leading to superview`, `top space to top layout guide`, `width equals 320`, `height equals 820`.

Height and width are connected as outlets to my class and I'm setting them in `viewDidLoad`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageHeightconstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBOutlet weak var imageWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

@IBOutlet weak var backgroundImage: UIImageView!

override viewDidLoad(){
    backgroundImage.af_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: photoURL)!)
    imageHeightconstraint.constant = backgroundImage.image!.size.height
    imageWidthConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.size.width
}
```

Now, my image is this:

[image]

it is 480x640px photo. I tried in my storyboard to set the mode to `center`, `scale to fill`, `aspect fill`, `aspect fit` and `top`.

For example, this is `center`:

[image]

`aspect fit`:

[image]

`aspect fill`:

[image]

but I don't know how to stretch this image from left to right and keep the aspect ratio, so the whole photo is visible and its left and right edges stick to the left and right edge of the screen.
I thought those two constraints could fix it:

```
imageHeightconstraint.constant = backgroundImage.image!.size.height
imageWidthConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.size.width
```

but it does not work. Maybe the problem is that the resolution of the photo is low (480x640), so the height is only that small? Can you give me any hint how could I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have the image stick to both sides of screen and maintain the aspect ratio, set these 4 constraints:

1. Leading Edge of ImageView to Leading Edge of SuperView.
2. Trailing Edge of ImageView to Trailing Edge of SuperView.
3. Top Edge of ImageView to Top Layout Guide Bottom.
4. Set an aspect ratio constraint:  ImageView Width equal to ImageView Height with `multiplier` `480:640`.  To set this, <kbd>control</kbd>-drag diagonally in the ImageView and select *Aspect Ratio* from the pop-up.  Then change the multiplier to `480:640`.

   [image: aspect ratio constraint]

Set the content mode for the image to `Scale to fill`.

Answer (score 2):

You may not be calling `setNeedsLayout()` and then `layoutIfNeeded()`.

In order for the UI to update, you need to tell the view to update, not just change the constraints.

Either way, if you want the imageView to consistently fill the screen and you shouldn't have a height/width on the ImageView, only hugging the sides. Also make sure those constraints are ignoring margins.

If you want the image to fill the imageView, set the resizing mode to aspectFill, and If you're looking for it to resize until the left/right or top/bottom reaches the edge of the view, aspectFit is what you need.